# RStudio on Windows can't use UTF-8 symbol (approx equal ≈) in data frame

Tags: r, text, utf-8, rstudio

I am trying to add a "≈" to a data frame.

You can add symbols like "+" and "-" to a data frame.
You can even add the ≈ symbol to a plot using

```
text(x,y, expression(""%~~%""))
```

but this won't work inside a data frame and I cannot find a way to do this.
I have tried just pasting a ≈ using paste("≈") and a few other equally feeble things.
For example:

```
x <- "≈"
print(x)
```

[1] "˜"

Here is a small example. The only difference that I would like to see is those middle two rows become ≈

```
df<-data.frame(prop=c(0.99, 0.97, 0.5,0.4,0.01, 0.02), symbol=NA)

df$symbol<-ifelse(df$prop>=0.95, "+","")
df$symbol<-ifelse(df$prop<=0.05, "-",df$symbol)
df$symbol<-ifelse(df$prop<=0.95 & df$prop>=0.05, "approximately equal symbol here",df$symbol)

df`
```

looks like

```
 prop                          symbol
1 0.99                               +
2 0.97                               +
3 0.50 approximately equal symbol here
4 0.40 approximately equal symbol here
5 0.01                               -
6 0.02                               -                              -
```

What I would like

```
 prop       symbol
1 0.99        +
2 0.97        +
3 0.50        ≈
4 0.40        ≈
5 0.01        -
6 0.02        -
```

Comment: `data.frame(x = "≈")` works for me. Is there a reason you need to use `expression()`?

Comment: I don't need to use expression() but when I type "data.frame(x = "≈")" I get
> data.frame(x = "≈")
  x
 ˜

Comment: Hmm. This could be an editor/OS issue. RStudio is supposed to natively support UTF-8 in code. If you're using a different editor you may need to configure a setting. If you're on window you may also need to make sure the file [is saved in UTF-8 encoding](https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/200532197-Character-Encoding-in-the-RStudio-IDE). What editor and OS are you using?

Comment: Using Windows 10 and RStudio

Comment: Can you isolate the problem more? If you run `x = "≈"` in your console and print `x`, do you get the same problem? (Meaning the issue has nothing to do with data frames.)

Comment: That appears not to work.

Comment: @Phil this issue is RStudio related, please do leave the tag on it.

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `'≈'.encode( 'cp437').decode ('mac-roman')` returns `˜`.  In other words: `≈` (U+2248,  *Almost Equal To*) has code `0xf7` in any of `['cp437', 'cp720', 'cp737', 'cp860', 'cp861', 'cp862', 'cp863', 'cp865']` and simultaneously, `˜` (U+02DC,  *Small Tilde*) has the same code in any of `['mac-croatian', 'mac-romanian', 'mac_iceland', 'mac_roman', 'mac_turkish']` encodings. Switch to `UTF-8` (in R for Windows, use `Sys.setlocale` witth codepage `.65001`…)

Comment: @JosefZ I'm not entirely sure what it is I'm supposed to do here. Encoding appears to already be UTF-8. I don't see an argument to Sys.setlocale called codepage.

Comment: `Sys.setlocale(locale='.utf8')` or `Sys.setlocale(locale='.65001')`

Comment: @JosefZ Thanks that does appear to work. This seems like something that should be possible without changing this setting though. I wonder if there is an alternate solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per the comments

Sys.setlocale(locale='.utf8') or Sys.setlocale(locale='.65001')